# Error : Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

This Question has been asked many times, I've gone through each an every solution, also tried to implement but none of them worked for me.

**Problem :**  Getting this error : `Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string` while filtering `NSArray` using `NSPredicate`.

**Coding Stuff :** By this way, I'm trying to filter my array

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:dataArray];

NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name BEGINSWITH[c] %@", searchText];

allProductData = [[array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]mutableCopy]; //Error is here
```

Now there are two array's`s where this is working for 1st array and same code is not working for 2nd array.

**Array 1:** Working fine for this array.

```
(
        {
        "_id" = 59483833710f853221c90a92;
        attributes =         (
                        {
                key = Atributos;
                value = "-";
            }
        );
        name = "Ades Soya Bebida Chocolate 946 Ml";
        price = "-";
        uri = "http://res.cloudinary.com/cloudimp/image/upload/u3kgmm8bx5lsmmacbnrl.jpg";
    },
        {
        "_id" = 5948383f853221c90a94;
        attributes =         (
        );
        name = "Ades Soya Bebida Chocolate 200 Ml";
        price = "";
        uri = "http://res.cloudinary.com/cloudimp/image/upload/hhafrnwocqoamhhievoy.jpg";
    }

)
```

**Filter Key:** `name = "Ades Soya Bebida Chocolate 946 Ml";`

**Array 2 :** Filter is not working for this array.

```
(
        {
        image = "http://images.qliktag.com/image/upload/w3tb9dutynou1hlooexn.gif";
        name = Abuelita;
        products =         (
                        {
                "_id" = 594c030f124244325;
                attributes =                 (
                );
                name = "Abuelita chocolate granulado";
                price = "";
                uri = "http://images.qliktag.com/image/upload/iiqfuiilstvksdycnfbc.jpg";
            },
                        {
                "_id" = 5931c73303f737086;
                attributes =                 (
                );
                name = "ABUELITA Chocolate";
                price = "";
                uri = "<null>";
            },

             { //Crashing app for this while reading this structure.
                "_id" = 5931c73303f737086;   
                attributes =                 (
                );
                name = (
                             {
                                language = @"en"
                                value = "SOYA"
                             },
                             {
                                language = @"de"
                                value = "SOYA Bebida"
                             }
                          );
                price = "";
                uri = "<null>";
            }
        );
    }
```

**Note:** In both the array `name` value is different.

Finally I want to filter `name`

```
name1 = "Ades Soya Bebida Chocolate 946 Ml"

name2 = Abuelita; //Crashing app for this while filtering.
```

Array is changing dynamically, it looks similar to this...

**example-1 :** App is crashing, with this error : Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string.

```
          ContactName[0] "ABC"
          ContactName[1] = XYZ
          ContactName[2] = (
                             {
                                language = @"en"
                                value = "PQR"
                             },
                             {
                                language = @"de"
                                value = "QWERTY"
                             }
                          )
```

**example-2 :** App is working fine

```
          ContactName[0] = "ABC"
          ContactName[1] = "XYZ"
          ContactName[2] = "PQR"
```

So, how should I filter such array...???

Comment: On array2, you want to filter because `name = Abuelita;` or because `name = "Abuelita chocolate granulado";` and `name = "ABUELITA Chocolate";`? If you want the second ones, you are missing a level.

Comment: Yes while filtering name2 it is throwing above error.

Comment: @Larme can you give me a proper example to filter Array2

Comment: I recreated your sample, it works. But, I could reproduce your issue ignoring some warning. `searchText` is not a NSString object. Before creating `resultPredicate`, could you log `[searchText class]`? And could you show the WHOLE error message, because I got " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string (lhs = Abuelita Ades Soya Bebida Chocolate 946 Ml rhs = {
    Abuelita = fez;
})'" and it's quite explicit and gives where the real issue lies (on the predicate, not the array).

Comment: searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText   ==> Using this filter within textDidChange

Comment: Yes, same error getting

Comment: Could you show the whole error message? Because the part on "rhs" gives clues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159143/discussion-between-ashish-langhe-and-larme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest `-[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:]`.

Test the type of `product[@"name"]`. If the type is a `NSString` use `-[NSString hasPrefix:]`. If the type is `NSArray` find the language that equals `NSLocale.currentLocale.languageCode`, then compare then use `-[NSString hasPrefix:]` on value.

```
- (void)testBeginsWithSearchText {
    NSArray<NSDictionary *> *data =
    @[@{@"image": @"http://images.qliktag.com/image/upload/w3tb9dutynou1hlooexn.gif",
        @"name": @"Abuelita",
        @"products": @[@{@"_id": @"594c030f124244325",
                         @"attributes": @[],
                         @"name": @"Abuelita chocolate granulado",
                         @"price": @"",
                         @"uri": @"http://images.qliktag.com/image/upload/iiqfuiilstvksdycnfbc.jpg"},
                       @{@"_id": @"5931c73303f737086",
                         @"attributes": @[],
                         @"name": @"ABUELITA Chocolate",
                         @"price": @"",
                         @"uri": @"<null>"},
                       @{@"_id": @"5931c73303f737086",
                         @"attributes": @[],
                         @"name": @[@{@"language": @"en",
                                      @"value": @"SOYA"},
                                    @{@"language": @"de",
                                      @"value": @"SOYA Bebida"}],
                         @"price": @"",
                         @"uri": @"<null>"}]}];

    NSString *searchText = @"SOYA";

    id beginsWithSearchText = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(NSDictionary *product, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        if ([product[@"name"] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
            return [product[@"name"] hasPrefix:searchText];
        } else if ([product[@"name"] isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
            NSUInteger index = [product[@"name"] indexOfObjectPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                return [obj[@"language"] isEqualToString:NSLocale.currentLocale.languageCode];
            }];

            return index != NSNotFound && [product[@"name"][index][@"value"] hasPrefix:searchText];
        } else {
            return NO;
        }
    }];

    NSArray *result = [data.firstObject[@"products"] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:beginsWithSearchText];

    XCTAssertEqual(result.count, 1);
    XCTAssertEqualObjects(result.firstObject[@"_id"], @"5931c73303f737086");
}
```